Share this site like when in commitment stage in Area 51?
Is there a way I can add a link like this:

So I can embed an ad for this site like so.

Go to the Definition page for our site: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2149?phase=definition and there's still a "Share" link available to get the embedded ad.
This will take someone to the Area 51 page, though, and it's not intuitive that they have to click "Visit!" once they get there.  It's probably best to link people to the main site.
  I suppose you could probably "borrow" the graphic and just change the embedded link to the main site at this point, I don't think anyone would get upset. 

@Skippy Yes, that's fine.  One of the things that Artem, and to a lesser extent myself, was that the questions there were in fact already on topic.  We're starting to gain some neuro experts, so keep the questions coming and many will be getting answers over the next few months.
